# Exit from SlingPlayer

Tags: javascript

I have written a Javascript to Exit from slingPlayer and it's not exit from slingplayer app

JS to exit

```
function windowclose() {
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
    return false;
}
```

Please suggest how to make it work.

Comment: This is not solvable a.t.m. because we don't know how the player works in your case and what code is available.

Comment: I have .net application that is run on slingbox and I need to perfome this task.using javascript and I know it's possible